# Full width and centered sub menu on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, nav

I have [a website](https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za) with a standard, centered navbar with submenu content. I am trying to achieve the same effect as [this website](https://www.myistore.co.za).

I need the menu dropdown to have inline items that are full-width and centered once they appear, as well as having the logo align to the left of the screen at about 30px (as opposed to currently just offset left of the page).

HTML:

```html
<div class="oi_logo_holder">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="oi_image_logo"><a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/" class="oi_text_logo_img"><img src="http://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Logo-2.png" alt="Oliver Karstel Photography" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 hidden-xs">
                <div id="menu_slide_xs"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a></div>
                <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
                    <ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="oi_main_menu">
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-2060 oi_pid-2060 current-menu-item">
                            <a href="http://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za#photography">Photos</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2061 oi_pid-2061"><a href="http://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/architecture-photography">Architecture</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-3191 oi_pid-3175">
                            <a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/articles/">Articles</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3207 oi_pid-3197"><a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/photography-articles/">Photography</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3221 oi_pid-3208"><a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/business-articles/">Business</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3220 oi_pid-3212"><a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/innovation-articles/">Innovation</a></li>
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3219 oi_pid-3216"><a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/lifestyle-articles/">Lifestyle</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-2059 oi_pid-2059 current-menu-item"><a href="http://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-2058 oi_pid-2058 current-menu-item"><a href="http://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za#contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-3195 oi_pid-17"><a href="https://okstaging.myrikdesign.co.za/category/video/">Video</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.oi_logo_holder {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 990;
}

.oi_logo_holder {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.oi_logo_holder {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.oi_text_logo a, .oi_main_menu li > a, .oi_footer_menu li a, .oi_slide_header_side, input[type="submit"], input, textarea, .oi_readmore_btn, .blog_title_a, .oi_img_holder, .oi_zoom_img, .oi_list_cats li a, .oi_pg a, .oi_ff_img_holder img, .oi_ff_mask, .oi_vc_port_mask, .oi_port_style_ii .oi_vc_potrfolio, #load_more_port_masorny_posts, .oi_a_holder, .oi_np_holder, .oi_port_nav, .oi_creative_p_content, .oi_crea_a, .oi_c_resize, .oi_c_details, .oi_modern_p_next.test, .oi_logo_holder, .oi_site_description {
    webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* MY OWN CODE BELOW */

#menu-main-menu-1 {
    padding-top: 17px;
    float: left!important;
}

.oi_main_menu li {
    position: initial!important;
}

.sub-menu {
    min-height: 73px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.oi_main_menu li > ul {
    padding-top: 28px!important;
}

.oi_main_menu li> ul li a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please create a working fiddle or snippet to better understanding

Comment: The example look like a simple bootstrap nav isn't it? Please provide more info on what you want!